# Generate last business day of the month variable in Python for US Calendar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, time

I would like to create a new column in my dataframe which is equal to the last business day of the month based on the US calendar, ideally in the format mm/dd/yyyy. My goal is to create this variable per day and set it for every day in the month corresponding to my existing `'DATES'` column. For example, for every day in January I want to create a a variable equal to `'01/31/2020'`, in a string format. For everyday in February I want to set a variable equal to `'02/28/2020'`, in string format.

If anyone has ideas would be of great help!

[Dataframe example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8eu1.png)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
from  datetime import date,timedelta
import datetime
import calendar

today=datetime.date.today()

last = today.replace(day=calendar.monthrange(today.year,today.month)[1])

if last.weekday()<5:
    print(last)

else:
    print(last-timedelta(days=1+last.weekday()-5))
```

Comment: On this, you can just easily change the output to whatever you want

Comment: Thanks for giving input, but this unfortunately didn't give the desired result! This created a column for which every variable was the last business day of the month for June 2020. My dataset is historical (ranges from Jan 2020 - May 2020) and I want to create a date column for earlier months. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> def is_weekend(dt):
    return dt.weekday() >= 5

>>> def is_holiday(dt):
    return False # You'll need to provide your own definition of holidays

>>> def last_workday(year, month, count=1):
    while count > 0:
        next_month = month + 1
        if next_month <= 12:
            next_year = year
        else:
            next_month = 1
            next_year = year + 1
        dt = datetime.datetime(next_year, next_month, 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        while is_weekend(dt) or is_holiday(dt):
            dt -= datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        yield dt
        year = next_year
        month = next_month
        count -= 1

>>> for x in last_workday(2020, 1, 12):
    print(x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

01/31/2020
02/28/2020
03/31/2020
04/30/2020
05/29/2020
06/30/2020
07/31/2020
08/31/2020
09/30/2020
10/30/2020
11/30/2020
12/31/2020
```